# Workflow manager 1.0 and external dll

Tags: workflow-manager-1.x

We are trying to publish a workflow and couple of activities to workflow manager. Our scenario is such that we need to create object of classes which resides in an external dll and those objects are calling a service(WCF) to fetch some data.

We have placed the DLLs in C:\Program Files\Workflow Manager\1.0\Workflow\WFWebRoot\bin\ and C:\Program Files\Workflow Manager\1.0\Workflow\Artifacts folders. Also we have created the AllowedTypes.XML file and have placed it in both the above folders.

The problem which we are facing is that when we declare a variable of a type which is in external DLL and try to invoke a method using InvokeMethod activity(we have also added the InvokeMethod activity type in AllowedTypes.xml) then we receive the following exception on the activity.publish statement.

`Workflow XAML failed validation due to the following errors:`

Cannot create unknown type '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities}Variable({wf://workflow.windows.net/$Activities}ObjectType)'. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId: 33bf5b07-9eda-4f63-bf58-6d85cbfdcd55. NodeId: MachineID. Scope: /WFMgrSample. Client ActivityId : af5e1771-90f7-4610-a2be-5f7b7ce48ee8.

any idea on what is wrong here!!!

Comment: Is the assembly the type is in referenced from the assembly that is doing the publishing?